# Does SE have a policy on people with multiple accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This appears to be an issue in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28086/how-to-draw-a-side-by-side-plot-mentioned-in-graphical-display-as-an-aid-to-ana).  Note that the [questioner](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11196/kh-kim) has rep=1, but a [person](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11209/kh-kim) answering the question (inappropriately, it's a really comment responding to another comment) has the same name and flair, but with rep=36.  The writing style and content also implies to me that they are the same person.  I'm not sure that any harm is coming from this, but it's definitely weird, and maybe we should have some kind of policy (or maybe we already do, I don't know).

Comment: The link to the questioner now is invalid because the accounts have been merged :-).

Comment: Note that myOpenID.com has more or less gone belly-up over the last few days to the extent that it ended up being completely removed from the stats.SE sign-on page. I had to create a new account myself as a result of this and others---potentially even the one you mention---may have had to as well. In addition the SE developers were dealing with cases where the automatic merging of accounts was failing (like mine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we do: we try to keep single accounts.  When you notice a duplication (thank you!), please just flag a moderator for attention.

Comment: I hadn't seen an option, I guess it would just go under flag->needs moderator attention->other, then?

Comment: Yes, gung, that sounds like the most convenient way to do it.  Thanks for your careful attention to these details!

Comment: Also, I can't accept an answer for *6 minutes*?! That's an awfully specific requirement.

Comment: @gung: I believe it's actually 6.283185... minutes. (No, not really.)

Comment: How do we know when there is a duplicate?

Comment: @Macro: The identicon (gravatar icon) will be identical assuming they use the same email address to register both accounts.

Comment: Thanks for these questions and answers.  I got a question migrated to Mathematics where I started an account but somehow I did something unintentionally that created a second acount there.  One account included my bonus transfer points and the other doesn't. Can someone eliminate the second one for me?

Comment: @Michael: Either flag one of your questions or answers at math.SE and put in the two user numbers of the accounts you want merged (You can see the user number in the top right search box in the two profile pages). Or you can send email to team+math@stackexchange.com with the relevant information. [See here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/merging-of-accounts).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion